# Reading and Writing to Firebase realtime database - getting force closed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to create an android app to practice firebase. I'm trying to read and write data to my firebase realtime database. I've already set it up following the documentation and it works good when I used this code snippet below:

```
// Write a message to the database
val database = Firebase.database
val myRef = database.getReference("message")

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
```

And I succesfully read the value from the `"message"` reference by doing this:

```
// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        val value = dataSnapshot.getValue<String>()
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: $value")
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
})
```

Then when I try to follow the instructions in the documentation in read and write to database to my `MainActivity.kt` it forced closes. This is my code in my `MainActivity.kt`. Can anyone explain why it got forced closed?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private var TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val database = Firebase.database.reference

        val editText = binding.userInput
        val writeBtn = binding.writeUserButton
        val readBtn = binding.readUserButton

        writeBtn.setOnClickListener{
            database.child("name").setValue(editText.text)
        }

        readBtn.setOnClickListener{
            database.child("name").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                binding.value.text = "${it.value}"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
2021-05-06 00:03:05.297 25802-25802/com.dicoding.firebasepractice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dicoding.firebasepractice, PID: 25802
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:161)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
        at com.dicoding.firebasepractice.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:34)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7504)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7476)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28661)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8142)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
2021-05-06 00:03:05.345 25802-25802/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25802 SIG: 9
```

Comment: share the crash report from logcat

Comment: @DeepakGoyal I just edited the question, contains the logcat

Comment: Try this `database.child("name").setValue(editText.text.toString())`

Comment: `editText.text.toString()` will work

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
database.child("name").setValue(editText.text)
```

It means that you are trying to write the "text" object to the database, which is actually not possible. When using property access syntax, the "text" object comes from the EditText's class [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#getText()) method. As you can see this method returns an object of type [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable). This object cannot be written in the database as it's not a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). So to be able to write the text that corresponds to the editText you are using, you need to write the String representation of the object. As @cutiko mentioned in his comment, simply calling "toString()" method on the "text" object will do the trick:

```
database.child("name").setValue(editText.text.toString())
```